# Prevent MDF sliding door from bending when hanged

Tags: mdf, wardrobe

I'm retrofitting sliding doors on a wardrobe. I decided to use the fixtures from Ikea Hasvik and custom made MDF doors.

The issue: the doors are bending towards the inside of the closet. They are not flat.

The doors are 2400 x 600 x 18 mm
Also the ikea system doesn't hold the doors from the top, but from the side.
I'm adding a picture that shows the hanging and you can probably see the start of the bending.

Any suggestions on how to prevent this bending?

Many thanks!
Paulo

[image]

UPDATE:
Thanks for your comments.

This was a pack of 3x custom made doors. I see 2 are slightly warped and the third one is OK. I'm not sure what caused it, but as mentioned in the comments could be 1) acclamation and/or 2) the fact I stored them straight up against a wall the first few days... or a mix of both.

I guess my question would be: Is there a way to counter the banana shape?

Comment: how long did you have it ? it could be the temperature change (acclamation)

Comment: Are the MDF panels flat when not hanging from the hangers?

Comment: Are you using the Hasvik hardware on the bottom of the door too?

Comment: Do you mean **tilting** and not bending?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. When I received the panels they were standing up against the wall and stayed like that for 2 or 3 days. I'm thinking that might have warped the panel. I've since installed the bottom fixture and seems to disguise it a bit. Is there any way I can give back its flat shape?

Comment: Short of installing battens, your best bet may just be to let it hang for a while and see if gravity pulls it flatter..

Comment: @keshlam Yeah, I guess I'll do that plus I'll add something to the inside of the wardrobe to push the bend out.